# what do you call a female single socket extension-style plug?

Tags: electrical

[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out what this female plug is called. I just need to buy the UK female plug, no cable, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a trailing socket (1-way).

Examples: [1](http://www.wilko.com/extension-leads/wilko-rubber-trailing-socket-1-way-13a/invt/5356540). [2](http://www.neweysonline.co.uk/newlec-trailing-socket-one-way-13a/1000009155/ProductInformation.raction), [3](http://www.gil-lec.co.uk/1-way-trailing-socket-13a-fc133whi), [4](http://essentialsupplies.co.uk/acatalog/13a_plugs_sockets.html)